# How can I get ownProps using reselect on redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I want to create a selector with memoization using reselect based on some `ownProps` of `mapStateToProps`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this by connecting the selector to a component using the `connect` method provided by [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), then passing the component props (ownProps) as the second argument to the selector.

**`container.js`**

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getVisibleTodos } from './selectors';

...

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state, props),
  };
};

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(TodoList);

export default VisibleTodoList;
```

You can then access those props in your selector

**`selectors.js`**

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getVisibilityFilter = (state, props) =>
  state.todoLists[props.listId].visibilityFilter;

const getTodos = (state, props) =>
  state.todoLists[props.listId].todos;

const getVisibleTodos = createSelector(
  ...
);

export default getVisibleTodos;
```

> *However*, this will **not** memoize correctly if you have multiple instances of the component you're passing props from. In that case, the selector would receive a different `props` argument each time, so it would always recompute instead of returning a cached value.

To share a selector across multiple components while passing in props **and** retaining memoization, each instance of the component needs its own private copy of the selector.

You can do this by creating a function that returns a new copy of the selector each time it's called.

**`selectors.js`**

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getVisibilityFilter = (state, props) =>
  state.todoLists[props.listId].visibilityFilter;

const getTodos = (state, props) =>
  state.todoLists[props.listId].todos;

const makeGetVisibleTodos = () => {
  return createSelector(
    ...
  );
}

export default makeGetVisibleTodos;
```

**If the `mapStateToProps` argument supplied to connect returns a function instead of an object, it will be used to create an individual `mapStateToProps` function for each instance of the container.**

With that in mind, you can create a function `makeMapStateToProps` that creates a new `getVisibleTodos` selector, and returns a `mapStateToProps` function that has exclusive access to the new selector:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { makeGetVisibleTodos } from './selectors';

...

const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
  const getVisibleTodos = makeGetVisibleTodos();
  const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
      todos: getVisibleTodos(state, props),
    };
  };
  return mapStateToProps;
};

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  makeMapStateToProps,
)(TodoList);

export default VisibleTodoList;
```

Now each instance of the `VisibleTodosList` container will get its own `mapStateToProps` function with a private `getVisibleTodos` selector. Memoization will now work correctly regardless of the render order of the containers.

---

This was adapted *(blatently copied)* from the [Reselect documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors)

Comment: Hi, I've got a question about this: what if I want to add parameters to makeGetVisibleTodos() ? Let's say that I have two components that uses the same parameterize selector, but their props naming are different, in this case this won't work because the underlying `getTodos` and `getVisibilityFilter` will fail.

Example: `betterFoobar = (id) => createSelector(foobarSelector, (foobarValue)=>id+foobarValue)`

My idea so far : `mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({ enhancedFooBar : (state, ownProps) => betterFoobar(ownProps.id)(state,ownProps)})` but I guess this won't memoize.

Comment: To make my point clearer, I ask this question because relying on ownProps in a selector tightly couples a React component API to a Redux state selector. This makes selectors unreusable across components, while they are an extemely powerful reusability tool. For example I'd like to use my selectors both in the main process and the renderer process of an electron, and in multiple components. The accepted solution seems not suited in this case (yet of course it answers the initial question and it might only need a few changes to work in my use cases).